# Why onchange behaves differently on React vs HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, onchange

### First Example

HTML: in the example below the console.log() is triggered when the text box is **modified** and **enter** is pressed.

```html
<input type="text" onchange="console.log(1)" />
```

React: in the example below the console.log() is triggered only one time, when **page is loaded**.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <input type="text" onChange={console.log(1)} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

### Second example

In this example I wrap the console.log() inside a function.

HTML: Same as before. The console.log() is triggered when the text box is **modified** and **enter** is pressed.

```html
<script>
    const foo = () => {console.log(1)}
</script>
<input type="text" onchange="foo()" />
```

React: in the example below the console.log() is triggered **on the fly**. Press enter is not needed and every input triggers console.log().

```
function App() {
  const foo = () => {console.log(1)}
  return (
    <input type="text" onChange={foo} />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Well, first I would say that when setting up an event, you should be supplying a callback function rather than just loose code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in [the React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

> With JSX you pass a function as the event handler, rather than a string.

When you say `onChange={console.log(1)}` the JavaScript expression `console.log(1)` is evaluated **immediately** (and on *every* render of the component) and the return value is assigned as the event handler (since the return value from `console.log` is `undefined` (which is not a function), this is useless).

---

> in the example below the console.log() is triggered on the fly.

See the [description of `onChange` in the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#onchange):

> We intentionally do not use the existing browser behavior because onChange is a misnomer for its behavior and React relies on this event to handle user input in real time.